# Spring Boot batch plus scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring batch so trying to schedule a batch works as a job every 5 seconds using spring boot batch and scheduler but somewhere I am missing something so getting below error.Please help me to solve this error.

**Error:-**

```
2017-03-12 02:23:26.614  INFO 8292 --- [pool-1-thread-1] com.spring.test.BatchConfig              : The time is now 02:23:26
2017-03-12 02:23:26.617 ERROR 8292 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitConstructors(Enhancer.java:721)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:499)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.enhanceFactoryBean(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:384)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:292)
    at com.spring.test.BatchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dcfce226.job(<generated>)
    at com.spring.test.BatchConfig.reportCurrentTime(BatchConfig.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

**application.properties:-**

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

**spring-config.xml:-**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd">



    <job id="job">
        <step id="step1">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="itemReader" processor="itemProcessor" writer="itemWriter"
                    commit-interval="1" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>

    <beans:bean id="itemReader" class="com.spring.test.Reader" />
    <beans:bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.spring.test.Processor" />
    <beans:bean id="itemWriter" class="com.spring.test.Writer" />

</beans:beans>
```

**Application:-**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-config.xml")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

**BatchConfig:-**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import({BatchScheduler.class})
public class BatchConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(BatchConfig.class);
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "HH:mm:ss");

    @Autowired
    private SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<String, String> chunk(1)
                .reader(new Reader())
                .processor(new Processor())
                .writer(new Writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() throws Exception{
        log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("JobID",
                String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();
        JobExecution execution =  jobLauncher.run(job(), param);
        System.out.println("Job Execution Status: " + execution.getStatus());
    }


}
```

**BatchScheduler:-**

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchScheduler {

    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory(
            ResourcelessTransactionManager txManager) throws Exception {

        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new 
                MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(txManager);

        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(
            MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) throws Exception {
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return launcher;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to figure out what is actually wrong with your code but it looks like some of your beans do not have no-args constructor.

Configuring batch with scheduler is relatively simple. I've just downloaded the code from [official batch guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) and extended it with small amount of my own code.

You can try the same:

1) Add `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` to application.properties file (just like you already have in your project)

2) Add `@EnableScheduling` to a `Application` class (just like you have in your code)

3) Create a `Component` class for scheduling with the next code:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.*;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Scheduler {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() throws Exception{
        JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("JobID",
                String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();
        JobExecution execution =  jobLauncher.run(job, param);
        System.out.println("Job Execution Status: " + execution.getStatus());
    }
}
```

That works well. Hope that having this example you'll figure out what is wrong with your own code.